# Disable data validation for row if cell "X" contains certain value

Tags: excel, vba

Data validation is normally activated for column B in the sheet, which stops anyone entering information with a "/" in.

Is it possible, if cell F5 contains the word `Apples` then Data Validation is deactivated for the row 5 and users can enter any information they like with "/"s and all?

Comment: My expectation is that you will need a macro to enable/disable data validation rules dynamically like this.  That is for Excel.
 Google sheets I know less about,
 though, I would not expect Google to have features that would allow you to get that custom with how you set up a file

Comment: @BenjaminGoldwater Thank you Benjamin. Sounds like a good way to go. Google Sheets works exactly like excel for the most part. Any idea what the Macro would look like for this?

Comment: Macro for Google sheets will have to be written in JavaScript/ Google apps script. I'm editing to add that tag &VBA and remove query.

Comment: Good luck getting help writing script for Google Sheets. I don't have experience doing this

Comment: @Benjamin It was a suggestion to use script. But, if OP wants VBA, feel free to help. I have added both tags.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code you can use in an Excel environment (not in Google Sheets)

define two ranges. `rng_test` should evaluate to `1` if data validation should be applied, and t `0` if no validation should be applied. `validate_this` should be run anytime you update the data set. Alternatively you could use a Private Target ByVal macro to run this macro any time someone updates certain cells that you think should trigger an update of data validation rules. (for more on this see: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm)

```
Sub validate_this()

Dim i As Integer
Dim rws As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng_test As Range, rng_validate As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng_test = ws.Range("C4:C7")
Set rng_validate = ws.Range("D4:D7")

rws = rng_test.Count

For i = 1 To rws
    rng_validate(i).Validation.Delete 'delete all old validations'
    If rng_test(i) = 1 Then
        validate (rng_validate(i))
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

And the following sub controls the actual data validation. I have written `valFormula` to reject any cell that contains a slash. You can update this variable to set up whatever rules you want.

```
Sub validate(rng As Range)

Dim rng_address As String
Dim valFormula As String

rng_address = rng.Address

valFormula = "=IFERROR(NOT(IF(FIND(" & Chr(34) & "/" & Chr(34) & "," & rng_address & ")>-1,1,0)),1)"

With rng.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation. not necessary since we did this above but can be good to keep for good measure'
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
       Formula1:=valFormula
End With

End Sub
```

My screen:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Benjamin. Very helpful. :)